# Insert a new element into an XML document using XQuery 3.0

Tags: xml, xquery

I need to insert a new element inside multiple nodes into an input XML document. Then, I need to update and retrieve the updated XML document.

I'm using **Anypoint Studio**, and since the xquery Transformation module supports XQuery 3.0, I figured that I can use the **insert-before** function, and since the element must be inserted in multiple nodes, I need to use a **for** loop to cycle through the multiple matches.

I'm new to xQuery so I apologize in advance for any beginner-type errors.

Here's a sample of the XML document I need to transform:

```
<Catalog>
  <Item>
    <Property1>Prop1</Property1>
    <Property2>Prop2</Property2>
    <Property3>Prop3</Property3>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Property1>Prop1</Property1>
    <Property2>Prop2</Property2>
    <Property3>Prop3</Property3>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Property1>Prop1</Property1>
    <Property2>Prop2</Property2>
    <Property3>Prop3</Property3>
  </Item>
</Catalog>
```

I need to insert the tag **Name** in position 1 of every **Item** node.
Something like this:

```
<Catalog>
  <Item>
    <Name>SomeName1</Name>
    <Property1>Prop1</Property1>
    <Property2>Prop2</Property2>
    <Property3>Prop3</Property3>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Name>SomeName2</Name>
    <Property1>Prop1</Property1>
    <Property2>Prop2</Property2>
    <Property3>Prop3</Property3>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Name>SomeName3</Name>
    <Property1>Prop1</Property1>
    <Property2>Prop2</Property2>
    <Property3>Prop3</Property3>
  </Item>
</Catalog>
```

I tried many queries, but got syntax errors every time, due to my poor knowledge of XQuery.
For example, I tried this query:

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare copy-namespaces no-preserve, inherit;
declare variable $document external;

declare variable $items := $document/Catalog/Item;

for $item in $items
return
   <Item>
     <Name>{ }</Name>
     { $item/Property1 } 
     { $item/Property2 }
     { $item/Property3 }
   </Item>
```

...but the resulting XML document (an array of string using the xquery transformation module in anypoint Studio) doesn't contain the root node.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your post, and add XQuery that you already tried.

Comment: Which element do you want to insert, where exactly? At least show the XML result you want to create. And if you are new to XQuery perhaps start with a working example of using `insert-before` before trying to use it with a more complex input and several nodes. If you have tried something, then show the exact code and the exact error you get.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'd like to insert the tag <Name> at position 1 in every <Item> node. I edited the post to clarify more my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Mulesoft and its Anypoint Studio.

I am using BaseX v.9.5.1

**XQuery**

```
declare context item := document {
<Catalog>
  <Item>
    <Property1>Prop1</Property1>
    <Property2>Prop2</Property2>
    <Property3>Prop3</Property3>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Property1>Prop1</Property1>
    <Property2>Prop2</Property2>
    <Property3>Prop3</Property3>
  </Item>
</Catalog>
};

<Catalog>
{
  let $new := <newElement>somevalue</newElement>
  for $x in ./Catalog/Item
  return <Item>
    {$new, $x/*}
  </Item>
  
}
</Catalog>
```

**Output**

```
<Catalog>
  <Item>
    <newElement>somevalue</newElement>
    <Property1>Prop1</Property1>
    <Property2>Prop2</Property2>
    <Property3>Prop3</Property3>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <newElement>somevalue</newElement>
    <Property1>Prop1</Property1>
    <Property2>Prop2</Property2>
    <Property3>Prop3</Property3>
  </Item>
</Catalog>
```

Comment: This solution solved the issue. Thanks a lot @yitzhak

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `insert-before` but

```
/*!element { node-name() } {
    Item ! element { node-name() } {
        insert-before(*, 1, <Name/>)
    }
}
```

would be one way to use it, although

```
/*!element { node-name() } {
    Item ! element { node-name() } {
        <Name/>, *
    }
}
```

does the job.

Note that XQuery update might be more adequate if your processor supports it (e.g. BaseX).

Comment: Great answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: I'll try this too. Thanks!